# Ensuring that workers finish tasks in the pool before loading the next for memory efficiency

Tags: python, memory, python-multiprocessing, pool

I have been trying to understand the multiprocessing module.

I have 1000 files (total size = 8 GB) that contain lines that I need to filter. I am creating two documents for each file filename_good filename_bad based on my filtering criteria.

- Globs below is a list of the 1000 filenames
- startroutine is my routine that does the filtering and writing
- I have tried altering chunksize and maxtasksperchild however I keep getting memory errors
- Each of the 8 processes is not finishing its startroutine before also opening the next file; hence memory errors.
- I would have thought maxtasksperchild would have caused each one to finish startroutine before being killed and a new process created.

`from multiprocessing import Pool
    if __name__ == '__main__' :
        with Pool(processes=8, maxtasksperchild=1) as pool:
            pool.map(startroutine,globs,chunksize=1)`